# Facebook Graph API: How to access user movies?

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

I want to read / write user **movie list** from a 3rd party app. Is it able to edit it? I haven't found any relating part in [docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api)? I want to update movie list user likes, so I need to show options available to choose. Is it a way to fetch movies from Facebook?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot like Pages via the Graph API, see

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/likes#Creating

> You can't perform this operation on this endpoint.

You could use the OpenGraph actions `video.wants_to_watch` and/or `video.watches`

See

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/opengraph/action-type/video.wants_to_watch/
- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/opengraph/action-type/video.watches/